# Hyperlink loop in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem, because I want to make program with make hyperlink for folders, I already have this part:

```
Dim a As String
Dim i As Long
Dim ark1 As Worksheet
Set ark1 = Arkusz1

For i = 1 To 3
    ark1.Cells(i, "A").Select
    a = "TR_" & i
    ActiveCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="C:/" & a, _
    SubAddress:="", ScreenTip:="a", TextToDisplay:=a
Next i

End Sub
```

But I have folders:
TR_1_Jon
TR_2_Allex etc.
And it is possible to make this loop that excel will be recognize only first part: "TR_1_******"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code to parse the sub folders and then use the same for hyperlinking :

```
Public Sub Test()
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    FolderName = "D:\" 'Replace it with selected folder
    Set FSOLibrary = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set FSOFolder = FSOLibrary.GetFolder(FolderName)
    For Each oSubfolder In FSOFolder.SubFolders
            MsgBox oSubfolder
    Next oSubfolder
End Sub
```

EDIT:

```
Public Sub NonRecursiveMethod()
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    FolderName = "D:\" 'Replace it with selected folder
    Set FSOLibrary = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set FSOFolder = FSOLibrary.GetFolder(FolderName)
    i = 1
    For Each oSubfolder In FSOFolder.SubFolders
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i, "A") = oSubfolder.Name
            Cells(i, "A").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(i, "A"), Address:=oSubfolder, SubAddress:=""
            i = i + 1
    Next oSubfolder
End Sub
```

Comment: OK It could be a help for me, but one more question: how can I save it to a sheet? I'm not advanced in VBA and I've never used this loop, I don't know how to do it to write down the results in individual cells. '''a=a+1 ark1.Cells(a,"A")=oSubfolder'''?